# Django QuerySet API to imrove Query Optimization

Tags: python, django

I have the below query that loops through three different tables and creates a records in the Master table.  The query works, but I wanted to know how I could gain efficiency and improve the query by leveraging Django QuerySet API,  if possible.

Django query:

```
s = Schedule.objects.get(pk = s_pk)
order = s.ordering_set.all()
days = s.dayscheduler_set.all()
for z in days:
    for x in order:
        s_val = x.room.spacetype.pk
        s = Space.objects.get(pk = s_val)
        q = Group.objects.filter(space = s, is_default = True)
        for y in q:
            daySch = DayScheduler.objects.get(pk=z.pk)
            room = Room.objects.get(pk=x.room.pk)
            group = Group.objects.get(pk = y.pk)
            M = Master.objects.create(room = room, dayScheduler = daySch, group = group)
            M.save()
```

Django Model:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible  # only if you need to support Python 2
class Schedule(models.Model):
    building = models.ForeignKey(Building, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    schedule_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.schedule_name


@python_2_unicode_compatible  # only if you need to support Python 2
class Ordering(models.Model):
    schedule = models.ForeignKey(Schedule, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    order_number = models.IntegerField()
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.order_number)


@python_2_unicode_compatible  # only if you need to support Python 2
class Room(models.Model):
    building = models.ForeignKey(Building, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    room_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    rmfloor_name = models.ForeignKey(Floor, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    sqfootage = models.IntegerField()
    spacetype = models.ForeignKey(Space, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    barcode_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.room_name


@python_2_unicode_compatible  # only if you need to support Python 2
class DayScheduler(models.Model):
    is_applicable = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    schedule = models.ForeignKey(Schedule, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    dayOfWeek = models.ForeignKey(DayofWeek, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)


@python_2_unicode_compatible  # only if you need to support Python 2
class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    space = models.ForeignKey(Space, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    building = models.ForeignKey(Building, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    is_default = models.NullBooleanField()
    task = models.ManyToManyField(Task)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.group_name)



@python_2_unicode_compatible  # only if you need to support Python 2
class Master(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    dayScheduler = models.ForeignKey(DayScheduler, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete = models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can use `iterator()` method. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#iterator

Secondly you can use `select_related()` or `prefetch_related()` when selecting objects with related objects.